# Why my bookmarks on Firefox for Android are not sync. to my desktop?

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

I have paired my desktop Firefox and Android Firefox. I found the bookmarks I added on my desktop can be sync. to my phone; but the bookmarks I added on my phone will not be sync. to my desktop. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the OP is you, this appears to be a [known issue](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/938182)

> Sync is both ways so there's something not working as intended. It could be that the computer hasn't synced yet, to confirm this, you can press the Sync Now button in the Firefox button (if you are in Mac it's under "Tools").
>
> If after that it doesn't work, I will recommend you to check in the logs if there's something that is not being downloaded to your computer.

[Another less optimistic post](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/941680)

> The phone bookmarks are not compatible with desktop Firefox. If you recover browser.db from the Firefox for Android that file contains your bookmarks. However it requires SQLite to read the file.